# I want to calculate Percentage of total and save it in a new column of PYspark dataframe row:

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Data should look like:

```
product total_spend needed

a        10          10%          

a        20          20%

a        30          30%

b        30          30%

b        10          10%
```

code using but not working:

```
df.withColumn('needed',df['total_spend']/F.sum(df['total_spend'])).show()
```

Comment: Can you indicate if answers helped in any way?

Answer (score 3):

Spark does not work this way, you first have to collect the data then you can use it for calculating the percent. Below is the sample code for the same, there are other ways as well one is this:

```
sum_spend = df.agg(F.sum(F.col("total_spend")).alias("sum_spend")).collect()[0][0]

df.withColumn(
    "needed",
    F.concat((F.col("total_spend")*100.0/F.lit(sum_spend)), F.lit("%"))
).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

A possibility:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(
   ("A", "X", 2, 100), ("A", "X", 7, 100), ("B", "X", 10, 100),
   ("C", "X", 1, 100), ("D", "X", 50, 100), ("E", "X", 30, 100)
    )).toDF("c1", "c2", "Val1", "Val2")

val df2 = df
   .groupBy("c1")
   .agg(sum("Val1").alias("sum"))
   .withColumn("fraction", col("sum") /  sum("sum").over())

 df2.show
```

Comment: works, but the "over" function needs a Window, like this: .over(Window.partitionBy())

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answer below.

```
df.withColumn("needed",concat(df.col("total_spend").multiply(100)/df.agg(sum(col("total_spend"))).first.mkString.toInt,lit("%"))).show()
```